# anchor tag with DOM while loop event always returning the last row element.parentNode in table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, while-loop

I have a table where each row contains an `<a>` tag in the first column to which an `onclick` event was added. The event fires a function that checks for the first `parentNode` equal to `<tr>` html row tag.  
The function works in that it always finds a `tr` parentNode, but for some reason it always finds the `<tr>` tag in the last row of the table. 
  I don't understand why, as the table structure means the the first parentNode will be a `<td>` tag then the `<tr>` tag of the current row from which the event fires:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Accept</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Push 1</a>
            </td>
            <td>Val 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Push 2</a>
            </td>
            <td>Val 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Push 3</a>
            </td>
            <td>Val 3</td>
       </tr> <!--alway returns the last row-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I bind the onclick event when I build the table in a `window.onload{buildTable();}` function [which works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces).  Here is a snippet:

```
    mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");
    // creates a <td> element
    mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");
    // create anchor element
    mybut = document.createElement("a");
    // set anchor text
    buttext = document.createTextNode("Push " + key);
    // append text to anchor
    mybut.appendChild(buttext);
    // set href attribute of anchor
    mybut.setAttribute("href", "#");
    // set event to anchor
    mybut.onclick = () => {MYMODCLASS.findParent(mybut, "tr");}
    // appends the Text Node we created into the cell <td>
    mycurrent_cell.appendChild(mybut);
```

```
    // find closest parentnode by tagname
    MYMODCLASS.findParent = function (el, tag) {
        while( el && el.tagName && el.tagName !== tag.toUpperCase()) {
            console.log(el.parentNode);
            el = el.parentNode;     
        } return el;
    }
```

```js
function builTb(/* element on which to append table */ id, /* new table id */ tablenme, /* set tbody row group names */ trbodyNme, 
    /* set table css class style */ clss, /* key:value pair data object */ dArr, /* header array */ hArr) {
// get the reference for the id element
var mybody = document.getElementById(id);
var head_bool = false;
//create get closest row element function
function getRows(/* set tr group name to search for */ trbodyNme) {
var rows = document.getElementsByName(trbodyNme);
console.log(rows);
}
//count rows within tbody element
function cntRows(/* table id to search rows */ tablenme) {
var col_tbodies = document.getElementById(tablenme).tBodies;
console.log(col_tbodies[0].rows.length);
}
// creates <table> and <tbody> elements
mytable = document.createElement("table");
mytablehead = document.createElement("thead");
mytablebody = document.createElement("tbody");

// creating all cells
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(dArr)) {// rows
if (!head_bool) {// check if header has been set
// creates a <tr> element
mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");
for (let h = 0; h < hArr.length; h++) {// header array
// creates a <th> element
mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("th");
// creates a Text Node
currenttext = document.createTextNode("cell is head row is " + hArr[h] + ", column key " + h);
// appends the Text Node we created into the cell <th>
mycurrent_cell.appendChild(currenttext);
// appends the cell <th> into the row <tr>
mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
}
// appends the row <tr> into <thead>
mytablehead.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
head_bool = true;
}
// creates a <tr> element
mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");
// row counter
var row_cnt = 0;
for(var k in value) {// columns
if (typeof value[k] !== 'function') {
// check counter in order to add <a> tag in first column
if (row_cnt === 0) {
// creates a <td> element
mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");
mybut = document.createElement("a");
buttext = document.createTextNode("Push " + key);
mybut.appendChild(buttext);
mybut.setAttribute("href", "#");
mybut.onclick = () => {findParent(mybut, "tr");}
// appends the Text Node we created into the cell <td>
mycurrent_cell.appendChild(mybut);
// appends the cell <td> into the row <tr>
mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
}
// creates a <td> element
mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");
// creates a Text Node
currenttext = document.createTextNode("cell is row is " + key + " row value is " + value[k] + ", column key " + k);
// appends the Text Node we created into the cell <td>
mycurrent_cell.appendChild(currenttext);
// appends the cell <td> into the row <tr>
mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
// increase counter
row_cnt++;

}
}
//set name of current <tr> row
mycurrent_row.setAttribute("name", trbodyNme);
// appends the row <tr> into <tbody>
mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
}
// appends <thead> into <table>
mytable.appendChild(mytablehead);
// appends <tbody> into <table>
mytable.appendChild(mytablebody);
// appends <table> into id element
mybody.appendChild(mytable);
// sets the border attribute of mytable to 2;
mytable.className = clss;
mytable.setAttribute("id", tablenme);
};
// find closest parentnode by tagname
function findParent(el, tag) {
  while (el && el.tagName && el.tagName !== tag.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log(el.parentNode.outerHTML);
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return el;
}
var arr = {
                    1: {id: 4, name: "monkey",val: 42, doc: "wer-123456"},
                    2: {id: 5, name: "bear",val: 3, doc: "wer-6086"},
                    3: {id: 8, name: "hippo",val: 102, doc: "wer-65409856"},
                    4: {id: 10, name: "cock",val: 78, doc: "wer-345629"},
                    5: {id: 9, name: "snake",val: 85, doc: "wer-126"},
                    6: {id: 20, name: "goat",val: 75, doc: "wer-965780"},
                    7: {id: 24, name: "elephant",val: 2, doc: "wer-709988"},
                    8: {id: 43, name: "pig",val: 201, doc: "wer-345"},
                    9: {id: 47, name: "cuttle fish",val: 85, doc: "wer-126"},
                    10: {id: 1, name: "squid",val: 75, doc: "wer-965780"},
                    11: {id: 100, name: "otter",val: 2, doc: "wer-709988"},
                    12: {id: 75, name: "sheep",val: 201, doc: "wer-345"}
                }
                var headArr = ["Accept","Id","Name","Number","Document"]
builTb("table-holder", "pricelist-tb", "pricelist-tr", "table-data", arr, headArr);
```

```html
<body id="table-holder">
</body>
```

**I can do this easily with jQuery but cannot on this project.  It must be a pure javascript solution.**
  Can someone please give me a clue to why the last row parentNode is always returned?

Comment: Hey!, Could you post the complete code please? I don't see the part where three rows are created, are you doing that manually or using some kind of loop?

Comment: Hi, I updated the code to contain my table builder and you can now see my error clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mybut is a global variable holding last content.

You can use this in call as element you are on. But mostly it is window inside JS code - if not "wired" in event attribute. Or event - also default function argument (arguments[0] - default if you do not specify argument/s list of your event handler), there are properties like currentTarget (element where your handler is) and srcElement (element you clicked on).

Short example from old code:

```
tabEl.innerHTML = "<table onclick=\"tabEdit(event, "+tabName+", '"+elName+"')\"<tr>...
```

"Wired" here - this should work here table object

```
function tabEdit(event, tabNm, elName) {
  var param = (function()
  {
    inputChange(event, tabNm, elName)
  });
  inp.onchange = param; /* here it is a local tabEdit variable - when param function
called event can be mouse click when pressing tab */
```

My question can give you some hints [IIFE-methods-leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235273/iife-methods-leaks)

**Very simple way to do something similar with your existing static table.**

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].onclick = function () {
  findParent(event.srcElement, "tr");
}
// find closest parentnode by tagname
function findParent(el, tag) {
    while( el && el.tagName && el.tagName !== tag.toUpperCase()) {
        console.log(el.parentNode.outerHTML
          .replace(/[\n\s]{2,}/g, '') // short result a bit
        );
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Accept</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tr><td>
    <a href="#">Push 1</a>
  </td><td>Val 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <a href="#">Push 2</a>
  </td><td>Val 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <a href="#">Push 3</a>
  </td><td>Val 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

**And here DOM Table build from scratch.**

```js
// find closest parentnode by tagname
function findParent(el, tag) {
    while( el && el.tagName && el.tagName !== tag.toUpperCase()) {
        console.log(el.parentNode.outerHTML);
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}

function buildTab() {
  var el0 = document.createElement('THEAD');
  var el1 = document.createElement('TH');
  el1.innerText = 'Accept';
  el0.appendChild(el1); // THEAD <- TH
  el1 = document.createElement('TH');
  el1.innerText = 'Value';
  el0.appendChild(el1); // THEAD <- TH
  el1 = document.createElement('TABLE');
  el1.appendChild(el0); // TABLE <- THEAD
  el0 = document.createElement('TBODY');
  el1.appendChild(el0);  // TABLE <- TBODY
  var keys = [1,2,3];
  for(var i in keys) {
    var el2 = document.createElement('TR');
    el0.appendChild(el2); // TBODY <- TR
    var el3 = document.createElement('TD');
    el2.appendChild(el3); // TR <- TD
    var el4 = document.createElement('A');
    el4.href='#';
    el4.innerText = 'Push ' + keys[i];
    el4.onclick = function () { findParent(this, 'TR') }
    el3.appendChild(el4); // TD <- A
    el3 = document.createElement('TD');
    el3.innerText = 'Val ' + keys[i];
    el2.appendChild(el3); // TR <- TD
    el0.appendChild(el2); // TBODY <- TR
  }
  document.body.appendChild(el1); // BODY <- TABLE
}
```

```html
<body onload="buildTab()">
</body>
```

Comment: There is one problem with your answer when binding an event on the table i.e. the click event fires when you click anywhere in the table, not just on the anchor tag.  I can cope with that as in my case the end result is more clean without the tag.  But finding a way to localise the function call can help in the future.